# How to access an object from main within a class

Tags: python

I need to use the Flask app instantiated from the main function within the InterestGroupsForm class so I can access a db.

InterestGroupForm class:

```
class InterestGroupForm(FlaskForm, app):
    c = app.db.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT TAG_TITLE FROM TAGS;')
    primary_tags_list = c.fetchall()
    print(new_list, file=sys.stderr)
    primary_tags = []
    .....
```

In the main function:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.db = None
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'a hard to guess string'
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
moment = Moment(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
user_db = {}
```

I should be able able to access the database normally (I've used the same code elsewhere for queries) but I keep getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/proj/main.py", line 53, in <module> class InterestGroupForm(FlaskForm, app): 
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Comment: show the full error + traceback

Comment: Doesn't give much other information:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/proj/main.py", line 53, in <module>
    class InterestGroupForm(FlaskForm, app):
NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the syntax of python classes. The brackets after your class name are for inheritance, you seem to be using as a constructor.

The syntax for python classes is:

```
class ClassName(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, args): # this is the constructor
```

`app` isn't a class. I suspect you want something like this:

```
class InterestGroupForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, app):
        c = app.db.cursor()
        c.execute('SELECT TAG_TITLE FROM TAGS;')
        primary_tags_list = c.fetchall()
        print(new_list, file=sys.stderr)
        primary_tags = []
        .....
```

However it's hard to say because I don't know where `new_list` is defined etc.